# Show video controls in html5 when right click is disabled

Tags: html5-video

I have disabled right click on my website's videos because I want to discourage downloads. To that end I use the following code:

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false" controls="controls" controlslist="nodownload"> 
    <source src="..."> video
</video>
```

However, with this users don't have the Controls' functionality. In particular, they cannot move forward or backwards with the keyboard arrows. Normally, to enable this functionality, you have to right click the video and select "Show Controls", as shown below:

[image]

Naturally, in my case that is not possible.

How can I enable those controls by default, so I can keep hiding that context menu? I've searched through default `<video>` [attributes](https://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_video_tag.cfm) but can't find any relevant for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To disable right-click on video tag and yet keep video controls, try my example below:

What the codes does:

- Gives your video tag an **ID** (see: `id="myVid"` )
- Uses Javascript's [`preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to **block right-click** on a specific item by its ID. 
  (*Eg:* You might still want right-click to work on other [non-video player] parts of the page.)

Testable code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="myVid" width="640" height="480" controls="controls" controlslist="nodownload">
<source src="filename.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>

<script>

//# use this line to prevent context menu in Video Element
document.getElementById("myVid").addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

</script>
```